# Get users attendance entry and exit in one row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with all entries for employees. I need to get all the working hours and the entry and exit time of the user in one record.
The table is like this:

[image]

How can I do that and also in case there is some missing entries or exit. Like one employee will have entry with no exit in some odd cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds LEAD entrytype to make sure there is a corresponding OUT row. Also, it divides the date difference in minutes by 60.0 (added decimal)

```
select t.empId EmpID, cast(datetime as date) [Day], datetime [Timein],  next_datetime [Timeout],
       datediff(mi, datetime, next_datetime)/60.0 TotalHours
from (select t.*,
             lead(datetime) over (partition by empid order by datetime) as next_datetime,
             lead(entrytype) over (partition by empid order by datetime) as next_entrytype
      from t
     ) t
where entrytype = 'IN'
      and next_entrytype='Out';
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `in`s and `out`s line up (that is, are strictly interleaved), you can use `lead()` and some filtering:

```
select t.empId, convert(date, datetime) as date, datetime as timein,
       next_datetime as timeout,
       datediff(minute, datetime, next_datetime) / 60.0 as decimal_hours
from (select t.*,
             lead(datetime) over (partition by empid order by datetime) as next_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where entrytype = 'IN';
```

Note that this formats the duration as decimal hours rather than as a time.  That part does not seem relevant to the actual question and just complicates the query.

Comment: it was a good solution until I found that is the user checked in and didn't check-out, the query add the check-in for the next day as out.

Comment: @ayman . . . As the first sentence states, this is based on an assumption, which seemed reasonable based on your sample data.

Comment: is there a way to show this record but with an empty exit or entry in case only one is available

Comment: @ayman . . . You've already accepted an answer to this question.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Using Row_number to identify IN and OUT related to which employee:

```
SELECT EMPID, CAST([DATEUPDT] AS DATE) AS Date,
MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRYTYPE = 'IN' THEN CAST([DATEUPDT] AS TIME) END) AS TIMEIN, 
MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRYTYPE = 'OUT' THEN CAST([DATEUPDT] AS TIME) END) AS TIMEOUT,
ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRYTYPE = 'OUT' THEN CAST([DATEUPDT] AS TIME) END), MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRYTYPE = 'IN' THEN CAST([DATEUPDT] AS TIME) END)))/60 AS DURATION
FROM 
    (
    SELECT A.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPID, [ENTRYTYPE]  ORDER BY [DATEUPDT]) RN1
    FROM EMPLOYEE_LOG A 
    ) X
GROUP BY EMPID, RN1, CAST([DATEUPDT] AS DATE)
ORDER BY EMPID, RN1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also "sessionize" in SQL Server - by using OLAP queries: With a counter that is at 1 when a new session begins and at 0 otherwise

```
WITH
input(id,empid,dttime,entrytype) AS (
          SELECT 1,125,CAST('2020-08-13 08:10:00.000' AS DATETIME),'IN'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,157,CAST('2020-08-13 08:01:00.000' AS DATETIME),'IN'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,125,CAST('2020-08-13 15:21:00.000' AS DATETIME),'OUT'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,125,CAST('2020-08-13 15:24:00.000' AS DATETIME),'IN'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,125,CAST('2020-08-13 17:24:00.000' AS DATETIME),'OUT'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,157,CAST('2020-08-13 15:01:00.000' AS DATETIME),'OUT'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,125,CAST('2020-08-14 08:10:00.000' AS DATETIME),'IN'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,157,CAST('2020-08-14 08:01:00.000' AS DATETIME),'IN'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,125,CAST('2020-08-14 15:21:00.000' AS DATETIME),'OUT'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,125,CAST('2020-08-14 15:24:00.000' AS DATETIME),'IN'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,125,CAST('2020-08-14 17:24:00.000' AS DATETIME),'OUT'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,157,CAST('2020-08-14 15:01:00.000' AS DATETIME),'OUT'
)
,
with_session AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , SUM(CASE entrytype WHEN 'IN' THEN  1 ELSE  0 END) OVER(
      PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY dttime
    ) AS sessid
  FROM input
)
SELECT
  id
, empid
, sessid
, CAST(MAX(CASE entrytype WHEN 'IN'  THEN dttime END) AS DATE) AS day
, CAST(MAX(CASE entrytype WHEN 'IN'  THEN dttime END) AS TIME) AS indtm 
, CAST(MAX(CASE entrytype WHEN 'OUT' THEN dttime END) AS TIME) AS outdtm 
, CAST( 
    MAX(CASE entrytype WHEN 'OUT' THEN dttime END) 
  - MAX(CASE entrytype WHEN 'IN'  THEN dttime END) 
  AS TIME
  ) AS totalhours
FROM with_session
GROUP BY 
  id
, empid
, sessid
ORDER BY
  id
, 4
, empid
, sessid
;
-- out  id | empid | sessid |    day     |  indtm   |  outdtm  | totalhours 
-- out ----+-------+--------+------------+----------+----------+------------
-- out   1 |   125 |      1 | 2020-08-13 | 08:10:00 | 15:21:00 | 07:11:00
-- out   1 |   125 |      2 | 2020-08-13 | 15:24:00 | 17:24:00 | 02:00:00
-- out   1 |   157 |      1 | 2020-08-13 | 08:01:00 | 15:01:00 | 07:00:00
-- out   1 |   125 |      3 | 2020-08-14 | 08:10:00 | 15:21:00 | 07:11:00
-- out   1 |   125 |      4 | 2020-08-14 | 15:24:00 | 17:24:00 | 02:00:00
-- out   1 |   157 |      2 | 2020-08-14 | 08:01:00 | 15:01:00 | 07:00:00
```