# date range Attendance for all employees including date with no entries

Tags: sql-server

how to get attendance for date range including all the date with no entry or exit transaction for all employees.

like if any employee has no transaction the record show that day, but with Absent in that day

and I need to apply this to all employees.

this is a sample data
[image]

I need the output to get all the days in date range even if there is no attendance for each employee.

I used this solution for (in) and (out) for employees,

[Get users attendance entry and exit in one row SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63657193/get-users-attendance-entry-and-exit-in-one-row-sql-server)

Comment: Use a Calendar Table, `CROSS JOIN` it to your Employee table, and the `LEFT JOIN` to your Attendance table.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Lots of users here will not be able to engage with that image. You're hurting your ability to get a good answer until you edit the question to include the data as formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Calendar table first. A simple one might look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.CalendarTable (CalendarDate date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                                CalenderYear AS DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderMonth AS DATEPART(MONTH, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderDay AS DATEPART(DAY, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderMonthName AS DATENAME(MONTH, CalendarDate),
                                JulianDate AS DATEPART(YEAR,CalendarDate) * 1000 + DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate),1,1),CalendarDate) + 1 PERSISTED); --Some example columns



WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6),
Dates AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY, T.I, '19000101')) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T)
INSERT INTO dbo.CalendarTable(CalendarDate)
SELECT CalendarDate
FROM Dates
WHERE CalendarDate < '21000101';
GO
```

Then `CROSS JOIN` that to your Employee Table, and then finally `LEFT JOIN` to your Attendence table. Resulting in a query like this:

```sql
SELECT CT.CalendarDate,
       E.[Name],
       CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'Absent' ELSE 'Present' END AS Attended
FROM dbo.CalendarTable CT
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Employee E
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Attendence A ON CT.CalendarDate = A.AttendenceDate
                               AND E.ID = A.EmployeeID
WHERE CT.CalendarDate >= '20200101'
  AND CT.CalendarDAte <= '20200831';
```

Comment: Would a TOP(DATEDIFF(...)) row goal in the Dates cte be a preferable location for the condition currently in the WHERE clause?

Comment: It's a one off run, @SteveC , so the performance is negligible. You see me using `TOP (DATEDIFF...)` more when the SQL is being called more often, such as in a function or stored procedure, and with multiple sets (like in an iTVF).